# "In the next" or "in next?"

Tags: grammaticality

Which variant is correct, "the main idea was in the next: bla-bla-bla" or "the main idea was in next: bla-bla-bla?"

Comment: I cannot think of a context where "in next" would be appropriate. What did you have in mind?

Comment: @MrHen: Good question, thanks. My native language is russian. And we've this structure of a phrase when we'd like to describe the main idea of something. E.g. "The main idea of this project was in the/... next: users can create free advertisements." I hope it works for you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more context, or a specific use I can't think of right now, I would not say either of those. I would say: ***“the main idea was the following: …”***